# How does Python stops itself a recurence?

Tags: python, recurrence

Imagine I calculate the Fibonacci sequence following the (obviously inefficient) recursive algorithm :

```
def Fibo(n):
    if n <= 1:
       return(n)
    else: 
       return(Fibo(n-2) + Fibo(n-1))
```

then my question is : how does Python known it has to stop the recurrence at `n=0` ?

After all, if I call `Fibo(-12)`, Python obviously answers `-12`, so why does it stop the recursion at `n=0` while calling `Fibo(12)` for instance ?

**Edit after a few comments :**
This question has nothing to do with the mathematical concept of recurrence. I know recurrence stops at the initialized point. I would like to understand how recurrence are implemented in computer. For me ti is absolutely not clear while a computer should stop while there is no explicit stop command. What prevents here Fibo(0)=Fibo(-1)+Fibo(-2) to continue endlessly ? Because after all I precised that Fibo(-1)=-1, Fibo(-2)=-2, ... and I might want to summ all negative numbers as well ... 
I confess in the last case I would prefer do a `while` loop.

Comment: It stops when `n <= 1`. That's the first line in the function.

Comment: @khelwood It's more tricky I guess, because for Fibo(2) it does not stop at Fibo(1) but when it has both Fibo(1) and Fibo(0). I realized while pushing button `ask` that it must stop once it has all the numbers required for the explicit computation. Does it means there is a verification of the type of the `return` each time a function is called ? e.g. Python knows Fibo(0), Fibo(1) are `int`, and Fibo(12) is Fibo(11)+Fibo(10), ...

Comment: @FraSchelle It stops when it does not need any further function calls. In this case, as soon as it reaches `2`, it will get the info that it needs `Fibo(0)` and `Fibo(1)` (from your last line of code) so it will go ahead and try to calculate those. In their calculation, there is no longer a recursive call (they exit from the to bracket of the `if`). So it just stops there.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you think is going on, or what type verification has to do with it. `Fibo(2)` calls `Fibo(0)` and `Fibo(1)`. Both of those return `n` (which is 0 and 1 respectively). That's the end of the recursion.

Comment: One can view a function to stop once the "return" is commited. That is why you often see the return statement outside a loop block, for instance. In this case however, we can see that the return statement (unless n <= 1) is defined as "return (Fibo(n-2) + Fibo(n-1)). In practice, we would expect the loop to finish here, due to the return statement. But since the return statement calls the function Fibo with two different parameters (n-2) and (n-1), we then enter that function. The parameter for the subsequent call(s) to Fibo decreases every time you call the function until n <= 1. Recursive

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yeah, thank you, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. But I still do not understand completely how Python knows it has no further need for function calls. Is there a way of tree generation, and Python asks itself : are all the leaf tree calculable ones ? (calculate being here float or int)

Comment: @FraSchelle There is a *keeping-track of what is pending/missing* to put it on loose terms. The calculation of `Fibo(k)` is pending because it requires `Fibo(k-1)` and `Fibo(k-2)` which in turn.... And so on. When everything it needs has been collected, it just calculates everything and gives you the results.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thank you again ! Now I'm thinking about procedure which would try to cheat around this rule :-) Do you know of algorithm which would defeat the pending/missing command ?

Comment: @FraSchelle Not sure what you mean there.. If it stop prior to collecting everything it needs, it will be unable to produce any results.

Answer (score 2):

It's functional, so it doesn't *run*, so it also doesn't *stop*.  You are (still) thinking in terms of iterative programming and assume some kind of loop here which needs to stop at some time.  This is not the case.

Instead in this paradigm you just state that the return value *is* the sum of the prior two numbers.  At this point you don't care how the prior numbers are produced, here you just assume that they already exist.

Of course they don't and you will have to compute them as well but still this is not a loop which needs a stop.  Instead it is a recursion which has an *anchor*.  With each recursion step the values will become smaller and smaller and once they reach a value below 2 you just return 0 or 1 without any further recursion.  This is your anchor.

Feel free to think of it as a "stopping point" but be aware that there is no loop happening which you need to break out of or similar.